# pchart change the color of percentage/values of pie chart

Tags: pchart

I cannot change the color of the percentage of the pie chart. I want the color to be black but it does not work.

This is where I am setting the default font settings. The RGB values are already 0.

```
$myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>"../fonts/Forgotte.ttf","FontSize"=>15,"R"=>0,"G"=>0,"B"=>0));
```

this is the pie chart

```
$PieChart->draw2DPie(320,350,array("Radius"=>250,"LabelColor"=>PIE_LABEL_COLOR_MANUAL,"WriteValues"=>PIE_VALUE_PERCENTAGE,"DataGapAngle"=>10,"DataGapRadius"=>6,"Border"=>TRUE,"BorderR"=>255,"BorderG"=>255,"BorderB"=>255));
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I am using the latest version of pChart, updated this month.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most obvious documentation for this on [pChart website](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.pie.draw2dpie.html):

> The color of the labels can be defined statically or dynamically setting
> LabelColor to:
>
> - `PIE_LABEL_COLOR_MANUAL` to manually provide a single color (`LabelR`,...)
> - `PIE_LABEL_COLOR_AUTO` to re-use the color of the data series.

Notice the `LabelR`, so whereas it's normally the:

```
array( "R" => 32, "G" => 42, "B" => 56 );
```

In this instance you must prefix them with 'Label'

```
array( "LabelR" => 32, "LabelG" => 42, "LabelB" => 56 );
```